# Can anyone recommend a well performing interface to allow the user to organize a large number of items in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, user-interface

Currently for "group" management you can click the name of the group in a list of available groups and it will take you to a page with two side by side multi-select list boxes. Between the two list boxes are Add and Remove buttons. You select all the "users" from the left list and click 'Add' and they will appear in the right list, and vice versa. This works fairly well for a small amount of data.

The problem lies when you start having thousands of users. Not only is it difficult and time consuming to search through (despite having a 'filter' at the top that will narrow results based on a string), but you will eventually reach a point where your computer's power and the number of list items apex and the whole browser starts to lag horrendously.

Is there a better interface idea for managing this? Or are there any well known tricks to make it perform better and/or be easier to use when there are many 'items' in the lists?

Answer (score 1):

Implement an Ajax function that hooks on keydown and checks the characters the user has typed into the search/filter box so far (server-side).  When the search results drop below 50, push *those* to the browser for display.

Alternatively, you can use a [jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), and set the minimum number of characters to 3 to trigger the search.  This will limit the number of list items that are pushed to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would get away from using the native list box in your browser and implement a solution in HTML/CSS using lists or tables (depending on your needs). Then you can use JavaScript and AJAX to pull only the subset of data you need. Watch the user's actions and pull the next 50 records before they actually get to them. That will give the illusion of all of the records being loaded at runtime.

The iPhone does this kind of thing to preserve memory for it's `TableViews`. I would take that idea and apply it to your case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you hit the nail on the head with the word 'filter'.  I'm not the hugest fan of parallel multi-selects like what you are describing, but that is almost beside the point, whatever UX element you use, you are going to run into a problem given thousands of items.  Thus, filtering.  Filtering with a search string is a fine solution, but I suspect searching by name is not the fastest way to get to the users that the admin here wants.  What else do you know about the users?  How are they grouped.

For example, if these users were students at a highschool, we would know some meta-data about them: What grade are they in?  How old are they?  What stream of studies are they in?  What is their GPA? ... providing filtering on these pieces of metadata is one way of limiting the number of students available at a time.  If you have too many to start with, and it is causing performance problems, consider just limiting them, have a button to load more, and only show 100 at a time.

Update: the last point here is essentially what Jesse is proposing below.